# Context menu for fabric.js not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm finishing my site on fabric.js and i've caught very annoying bug.

I have made a handler for right mouse click, that open context menu. 
It works fine on most times, but for Safari and sometimves for chrome, it opens context menu for just a moment and closes it right instead.

For some reason after contextmenu listener mouse.up event fires ***only in Safari***.

I need to prevent mouse.up after contextmenu somehow.

Here is the code.

```
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        var activeGroup  =  canvas.getActiveGroup();
        var objectInGroup = false;


        var relativeX = e.clientX;
        var relativeY = e.clientY;

        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();

        var clickPoint = new fabric.Point(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);

        //debugger;
        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(e.originalEvent);
        var objects = canvas.getObjects();
        for (var i = objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (objects[i].containsInGroupPoint(clickPoint) || objects[i].containsPoint(clickPoint)) {

                console.log(i);
                if (activeGroup)
                {
                    for (var y = 0, len = activeGroup._objects.length; y < len; y++) {
                        if (activeGroup._objects[y]==objects[i])
                        {
                            objectInGroup = true;
                        }

                    }                       

                }


                if (activeObject!=objects[i] && !objectInGroup)
                {   
                    canvas.deactivateAll();
                    canvas.setActiveObject(objects[i]);

                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if (i < 0) {

        }

        activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();





        //console.log(activeObject);

        if(activeObject == null && activeGroup == null){

            var obj = canvas.getObject();

        }

        console.log(obj);

        console.log(e.pageX + " - " + e.pageY);
        console.log(offset.left + " - " + offset.top);

        if(jQuery("#prozrachnost").is(':visible')){

            jQuery("#prozrachnost").hide();
            jQuery(".rect_books").hide();
            jQuery(".cap_palitra").hide();
        }else{
            jQuery("#prozrachnost").css({
                'position':'absolute', 'top' : relativeY, 'left' : relativeX, 'width' : '171px', 'height' : 'auto', 'z-index': 1
            });
            jQuery("#prozrachnost").show();
            var ch = jQuery('#prozrachnost').find('.button_menu_top').height();
            var cw = jQuery('#prozrachnost').find('.button_menu_top').width();
            jQuery('#prozrachnost').find('.button_menu_bottom').css({height:ch});
            jQuery('#prozrachnost').find('.button_menu_center').css({ 
                left : ((cw / 2) - (jQuery('#prozrachnost').find('.button_menu_center').width() / 2)) + 'px' 
            });



            var type = '';

            jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_top').hide();
            jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a').hide();

            if(activeObject){
                if(activeObject.get('myType') == 'text' || activeObject.get('myType') == 'image'){
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_top').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.del').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.palitra').show();
                }

                if(activeObject.get('myType') == 'rect' || activeObject.get('myType') == 'captionborder'){
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.books').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.del').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.palitra').show();
                }

                type = activeObject.get('myType');

            }else if (activeGroup){

                if(activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType') == 'text' || activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType') == 'image'){
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_top').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.del').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.palitra').show();
                }

                if(activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType') == 'rect' || activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType') == 'captionborder'){
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.books').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.del').show();
                    jQuery('#prozrachnost .button_menu_bottom a.palitra').show();
                }

                type = activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType');
            }

            console.log(activeGroup);

            jQuery("#prozrachnost a.button_link").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
                var activeGroup  =  canvas.getActiveGroup();
                var btn = jQuery(this);

                var type = '';

                if(activeObject) { type = activeObject.get('myType'); }
                else if (activeGroup) { type = activeGroup._objects[0].get('myType'); }


                if(btn.hasClass('books')){
                    if(type == 'rect'){ jQuery("#RECTBACK").click(); }
                    if(type == 'captionborder'){ jQuery("#CAPBACK").click(); }
                }

                if(btn.hasClass('palitra')){

                    if(type == 'rect'){
                        jQuery(".cap_palitra").hide();
                        jQuery(".ttext_color").hide();
                        jQuery(".rect_books").show();
                    }

                    if(type == 'captionborder'){
                        jQuery(".rect_books").hide();
                        jQuery(".ttext_color").hide();
                        jQuery(".cap_palitra").show();
                    }

                    if(type == 'text'){
                        jQuery(".rect_books").hide();
                        jQuery(".cap_palitra").hide();
                        jQuery(".ttext_color").show();
                    }

                }

                if(btn.hasClass('del')){

                    if(type === 'text') { jQuery("#ITDEL").trigger('click'); }
                    if (type === 'image'){ jQuery("#ITDEL").trigger('click'); }
                    if(type === 'rect'){ jQuery("#RCBDEL").trigger('click'); }
                    if (type === 'captionborder'){ jQuery("#RCBDEL").trigger('click'); }

                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // undo and redo buttons
    jQuery('#undo').click(function() { replay(w.undo, w.redo, '#redo', this); });
    jQuery('#redo').click(function() { replay(w.redo, w.undo, '#undo', this); });

    // undo and redo buttons 2
    jQuery('#undo1').click(function() { replay(w.undo, w.redo, '#redo1', this); });
    jQuery('#redo1').click(function() { replay(w.redo, w.undo, '#undo1', this); });

    //disable rotation/scling on selected group
    canvas.observe('selection:created', function (e){
        if (e.target.type === 'group') {
            e.target.hasControls = false;
        }
    });     



    canvas.on('mouse:up',function(option){

        if(jQuery("#prozrachnost").is(':visible')){
            jQuery("#prozrachnost").hide();
            jQuery(".rect_books").hide();
            jQuery(".cap_palitra").hide();
        }

        //console.log('up');

        if(option.target){
            if (option.target == window.change_item) {window.change_item=option.target;}
        }

        if(option.target){ methods.active(option.target.get('myType'),option); }
    });
```

Would someone give me a clue on this please.

Here is the link http://motivashka-board.ru/konstruktor.html

And this is how context menu looks 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem myself.
I've moved disabling code from mouse.up to mouse.down.

```
        if(jQuery("#prozrachnost").is(':visible')){
        jQuery("#prozrachnost").hide();
        jQuery(".rect_books").hide();
        jQuery(".cap_palitra").hide();
    }
```

That did the trick.